# Protecting critical section in interrupt

Tags: c, interrupt, critical-section

I want a solution for this problem than disabling interrupts  while if condition being executed. I'm working on pic16f877a. and want very simple and basic solution.

```
static int counter=0;
void main()
{
  while(1)
 {
   if(counter)
   {
    counter--;
    //code 
    }
  }


InterruptSerial()
{
 counter++;
 //code
}
```

To execute counter--; it is translated into

```
 load    counter value 
 decrement  loaded value 
 assign     new value in counter register
```

If an interrupt happened while executing this code before reaching the assign instruction this will result in wrong behavior.

Normal solution will be

```
void main()
{
  while(1)
 {
   if(counter)
   {
    disableInterrupts();
    counter--;
     //code
     enableInterrupts(); 
   }
}
```

How to solve this without disabling interrupts ?

Comment: What do you have access to? Can you use 
[std::atomic](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic)?

Comment: The operation will be atomic, so executed in a single instruction which cannot be interrupted (unless you are using an 8-bit processor). Also `volatile int counter = 0;` tells the compiler to make no assumptions about `counter`.

Comment: I'm using 16-bit processor.

Comment: @WeatherVane, volatile should not be considered atomic.
In his question, he mentions static, but it does show three instructions.

Comment: @Ben indeed it should not, but in the example the operation is atomic. I left out the `static` qualifier because a global variable *is* static.

Comment: Does your processor support atomic CAS operations?  If so, this is the easiest solution.  For a 16-bit processor, perhaps not though.  In that case, you will need a DI/EI pair on dec and inc (unless done inside an interrupt where interrupt nesting is disabled).  Also, counter should be `volatile` so that the compiler doesn't help you into an issue.

Comment: Why are you unwilling to disable interrupts?

Comment: @WeatherVane Well, `static` in such a case does limit the variable to internal linkage.

Comment: @Sneftel to decrease interrupt latency as minimum as possible.

Comment: Disable the interrupts or dedicate a single register to this counter. Are you already using both of your timer/counter registers? You could hook that interrupt signal to the clock input of one of those timers and avoid interrupting your code altogether.